# NoClassDefFoundError javax/jms/Message even when specifying classpath

Tags: java, exception, jms, noclassdeffounderror

I'm experiencing an error when running certain java code pertaining to JMS. I've been pulling my hair out for 2 days trying to figure this out.

The exception I'm getting is "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/Message"

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/Message
    at Asci.ActiveBatch.JMSAgent.JMSManager.createMsg(JMSManager.java:195)
    at Asci.ActiveBatch.JMSAgent.JMSService.SendMessageHandler(JMSService.java:160)
```

Without going into TOO much detail, this is referring to this line:

```
public static void createMsg(String icf, String url, String cf, String QName, String msgText, String[] props, String user, String pass) throws Exception {
    JMSProducer.produceMsg(icf, url, cf, QName, msgText, props, user, pass);
}
```

(Don't ask why that function is just basically mapping to another one... I didn't originally write this code)

I'm calling this code as

```
java -jar /path/myjarfile.jar
```

javax.jms.jar is included in that jar's manifest (and it exists in that location), but just in case I've also tried including a classpath to my lib folder (which contains javax.jms.jar, of course) as follows:

```
java -classpath /path/lib:. -jar /path/myjarfile.jar
```

I've had no luck so far. I'm not sure what to do or how to debug this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Clearly, this code compiles, so these classes must be available (at least) during compile-time.

Thanks.

EDITS:

1) I did also try
    java -classpath /path/lib/javax.jms.jar:. -jar /path/myjarfile.jar

2) This problem is happening during run-time, not compile-time.

3) So, I have other code that calls the same method in the same jar file that works. There's something not meshing right when calling this code from a particular jar. I've checked and re-checked my other code to make sure it's identical (which it was/is), so it doesn't seem like a code problem. There seems to be some messed up reference or something, somewhere.

Comment: Have you tried java -classpath /path/lib/javax.jms.jar:. -jar /path/myjarfile.jar ?

Comment: I don't really understand what JMS is, but I do know that a 'NoClassDefFound'-Exeption often means, that something was found at compile time, but not at runtime.

Comment: @ToddMurray Yes, I've tried specifying the jar explicitly.

Comment: @SatelliteSD It's happening at runtime. I see 0 errors during compiletime.

Comment: What JMS provider are you using? Typically you need to use their JMS JARs.

Comment: We use a bunch of different ones around here. The two that I'm testing with are GlassFish and OpenJMS. I would understand if there was some exception thrown when making an API call, but it seems to die on the import, so I don't think that that's the issue.

Comment: Nobody has any ideas as to debugging this??

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that you are having a classloader conflict where one version of  *javax.jms.Message* is loaded in one classloader, and then it is butting heads with a different version loaded from a different classloader.

Can you add a static initializer to JMSManager and JMSProducer to do something like this ?

```
static {
   System.out.println("MESSAGE CLASSLOADER IN JMSMANAGER:" + 
       javax.jms.Message.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
}
```

If they print out different URLs, it means you have multiple copies of javax/jms/Message.class in the classpath, and your two JMS guys are loading different ones each.

If not..... well, post what you see :)

Comment: OK I've added the static initializers to the classes in question. I was unable to get any output from JMSManager or JMSProducer, however, the next class up (where these things get called from) is called "JMSService." I added the static initializer to that class and now I get an error as follows:   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/Message   
        at Asci.ActiveBatch.JMSAgent.JMSService.<clinit>(JMSService.java:34)   
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: You are missing another resource.  Decompile Asci.ActiveBatch.JMSAgent.JMSService and look at its dependencies.  You will need to find jars for those.

Comment: @ToddMurray, I have the source code for that class. The project it's in has a reference to javax.jms.jar, which contains javax.jms.Message ...

Answer (score 0):

When adding a `.jar` to the classpath, you need to reference the jar directly, not the folder it's in.

```
java -classpath /path/lib/JMS.jar:. -jar /path/myjarfile.jar
```

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry for the misinformation. I actually did try doing this.....   java -classpath /path/lib/javax.jms.jar:. -jar /path/myjarfile.jar

Answer (score 0):

Create a lib folder inside WEB-INF if it is not there already. Put this jar : **javax.jms.jar** and restart server